# How can I find a simple upper bound for this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, upper-lower-bounds

I want to compute a simple upper bound for

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{T-1} (k x^{k-1})^2$$

that depends on both $x \in [-1,1]$ and $T$.

I can compute

$$S = \frac{(-2 T^2 + 2 T + 1) x^{2 T + 2} + T^2 x^{2 T} + (T - 1)^2 x^{2 T + 4} - x^4 - x^2}{x^2 (x^2 - 1)^3}.$$

But can I compute an upper bound on $S$ that is simpler? For example, a bound that we can see immediately that $S(0) = 0$ and $S(1)$ is bounded. 
An obvious upper bound for this sum is when $x = 1$, which is $\sum_{k=1}^{T-1} k^2 = T(2 T^2 - 3T +1)/6$, but I'm looking for an upper bound that depends on $x$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your formula for $S$ is a bound and depends on $x$. Do you have any other condition that excludes your formula for $S$ as a choice?

Comment: @KLstream I'm looking for a simpler expression. For example, one that we can see immediately that $S$ is finite at 1 and $S = 0$ at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? It decouples the summations of $k^2$ and $x^{2(k-1)}$ and hence  gives a product bound: 
$$
S^2 = (\sum_{k=1}^{T-1} k^2 x^{2(k-1)})^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^{T-1} k^4  \sum_{k=1}^{T-1}  x^{4(k-1)}\\
= \frac{T (T - 1) (2 T - 1) (3 T^2 - 3 T - 1)}{30} \cdot \frac{x^4 - x^{4 T}}{x^4 - x^8}
$$
which gives $S(x=0) = 0$ and $S^2(x=1) \le \frac{T (T - 1)^2 (2 T - 1) (3 T^2 - 3 T - 1)}{30} $.